# ssh config for multiple bitbucket accounts - Simple example, but getting 'remote end hung up unexpectedly'

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-keys

Suppose my bitbucket user name is "jon" and I have some personal projects at `https://bitbucket.org/jon`.

Suppose I then join a development team that has a bitbucket account called "devteam" which can be found at `https://bitbucket.org/devteam`

Then suppose I am setting up a new machine.  I generate an ssh key pair, `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` which are in `~/.ssh`.  Then my dev team leader adds my `id_rsa.pub` public key to the devteam account on bitbucket.  Now I can clone the projects from the devteam account and get to work.

Next I want to interact with my own `jon` account.  However, I cannot add the `id_rsa.pub` key to my bitbucket account because bitbucket tells me that that key has already been added to an account.  This means I have to generate a second key pair.  So I run `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/jon -C "jon"` as instructed here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168 and then I add this `jon.pub` key to my `jon` account at bitbucket.

Now that I have two key pairs, `id_rsa` and `jon`, I have to configure which key gets used when.  Following the instructions at the bitbucket help page linked to above, I create a `config` file in my `~/.ssh` directory with the following contents:

```
Host devteam
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host jon
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/jon
```

I am then informed that I can make the following substitution: From `git@bitbucket.org:jon/reponame.git` to `git@jon:jon/reponame.git`

So I try to execute the following command: `git clone git@jon:jon/reponame.git` and I get the following error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/jon/dev/reponame/.git/
Bad owner or permissions on /home/jon/.ssh/config
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What did I do wrong?

Edit: Here are the file permissions in my `~/.ssh` directory:

```
[jon@linuxmachine ~/.ssh]
 1$ ls -alh
total 32K
drwx------.  2 jon 4.0K Jan 18 19:20 ./
drwx------. 11 jon 4.0K Jan 18 19:34 ../
-rw-rw-r--.  1 jon  132 Jan 18 19:20 config
-rw-------.  1 jon 1.8K Jan 18 15:21 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--.  1 jon  406 Jan 18 15:21 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------.  1 jon 1.7K Jan 18 18:45 jon
-rw-r--r--.  1 jon  390 Jan 18 18:45 jon.pub
-rw-r--r--.  1 jon  808 Jan 18 18:40 known_hosts
```

Comment: Go into `/home/jon/.ssh/` and run ls -alh to check if you are the owner of config. Also try to run git clone with `-v` flag.

Comment: Also checks the permission of the files.

Comment: Hmm, okay I've edited to add that info.  It looks like me and my group have read and write access to the config file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem.
After i changed permissions of the file `~/.ssh/config` to `-rw-r--r--`, the error

```
Bad owner or permissions on /home/username/.ssh/config
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

disappeared.

Write in console:

```
cd ~/.ssh
chmod 644 config
```

Comment: And: `chown $USER config` just in case.

Answer (score 0):

It is regards to RSA file that appears on `../.ssh/` folder I fixed this by deleting any corrupt file and then generate again as you install GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

These commands should fix the problem:

```
chown $USER ~/.ssh/config
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
```

Prefix with `sudo` if the files are owned by different user.

If more files are affected, replace `config` with `*`.

In `man ssh` we can read:

> Because of the potential for abuse, this file must have strict permissions: read/write for the user, and not
>   writable by others.  It may be group-writable provided that the group in question contains only the user.