# How to setup two different Github accounts for two different repositories through SSH?

Tags: git, github, ssh

Before start I should say I have read a lot of topics (listed at the end of this post) about this issue but none is working for me or maybe I am missing something trivial in here.

At first I did clone the repository using HTTPS but then I switched to SSH following the docs from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/). I did generate each of the SSH key and add them to the `ssh-agent` following the docs from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).

In a few lines (fake data used, `~` means my home directory) this is what I've done:

```bash
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "first@gmail.com"
Enter a file in which to save the key (~/.ssh/id_rsa): [Press enter]
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]
Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]

$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "second@gmail.com"
Enter a file in which to save the key (~/.ssh/id_rsa_second): [Press enter]
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]
Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]

$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 12697

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: ~/.ssh/id_rsa (~/.ssh/id_rsa)

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_second
Identity added: ~/.ssh/id_rsa_second (~/.ssh/id_rsa_second)

$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:gb+Gn4SqiyAP5ABUsmX6Xz11RHTSvDsWgEE5P2R2VTE ~/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
4096 SHA256:yxWMompayDNtYjv5y+FfJl7OpQ5Qu90kPgdXXvx6DRA ~/.ssh/id_rsa_second (RSA)
```

The next step was create the `~/.ssh/config` file with the following content:

```
#first account
Host github.com-first
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#second account
Host github.com-second
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_second
```

I stopped here and give this a try by adding the SSH pub key for `id_rsa_second` to the repository where I want to use it (this doesn't need explanation). Next `git pull`:

```bash
$ git pull
Bad owner or permissions on /home/rperez/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then I tried the following:

- Change the `.git/config` file to the following:

  ```
  [remote "origin"]
      url = git@github.com-second:repo/repo.git
      fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  ```

But it didn't work and by this I mean I got exactly the same error as before.

What I am doing wrong? What I am missing?

What I have read:

- [How to properly configure ssh keys to multiple remote accounts involving github and bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823162/how-to-properly-configure-ssh-keys-to-multiple-remote-accounts-involving-github)
- [GitHub: Multiple account setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552809/github-multiple-account-setup)
- [Multiple github accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)
- [Quick Tip: How to Work with GitHub and Multiple Accounts](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574)
- [Can't get Multiple SSH keys to work for multiple github accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034769/cant-get-multiple-ssh-keys-to-work-for-multiple-github-accounts)
- [Multiple SSH Keys settings for different github account](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996)

> Note: The title may seem confusing but it is correct because it is what I want to achieve I am just talking about one example but at the end I should be able to setup more than one account pointing to different repositories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh config for multiple bitbucket accounts - Simple example, but getting 'remote end hung up unexpectedly'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409761/ssh-config-for-multiple-bitbucket-accounts-simple-example-but-getting-remote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because of this error:

> Bad owner or permissions on /home/rperez/.ssh/config

Ssh is picky (for security reasons) about the permissions of sensitive files.

[man ssh](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html) says:

```
~/.ssh/config
        This is the per-user configuration file. The file format and configuration 
        options are described in ssh_config(5). Because of the potential for abuse,
        this file must have strict permissions: read/write for the user, and not
        writable by others.
```

So check the file permissions of `/home/rperez/.ssh/config`. They should be 0644 (`-rw-r--r-`).